# How to show a progress bar in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

i'm kind of new using `AngularJs framework` and i am not that good in English. so i hope somebody can help me solve my problem and never mind my grammar hehe. i know mostly of progress bar in `angularjs` triggered by `ng-show`, but what if i want to put a progress bar before an `object` tag loads. for example

```
    <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
   aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    <object width="400" height="400" data="file.pdf"></object>
  </div>
</div>
```

let assume that that "file.pdf" is being fetch from the server. that being said it needs time to load, so i want to put a progress bar on that time while the data if being fetch from the server and hide it when the object is fully loaded thank you guys.

data flow example : 
(file.pdf) ----Fetching---- [controller]----Progress bar--View(html)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you out. This is a basic example for showing and hiding a spinner bar on button click.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to LearnKode - A code learning platform</title>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
   .loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }

   @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
   }
   html, body, container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
   }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="changeExample">
        <div class="container" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <button class="btn" ng-click="ShowSpinner()">Show Spinner</button>
   <button class="btn" ng-click="HideSpinner()">Hide Spinner</button>
            <div ng-if="ShowSpinnerStatus" class="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
   var app = angular.module("changeExample", []);
   app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ShowSpinnerStatus = true;
    
    $scope.ShowSpinner = function(){
     $scope.ShowSpinnerStatus = true;
    };
    $scope.HideSpinner = function(){
     $scope.ShowSpinnerStatus = false;
    };
   }]);
  </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can show and hide the spinner on a service call like this.

```
        $scope.ShowSpinner();
        LoginService.authenticateUser(userName, password).then(
            function(response){
                $scope.HideSpinner();
                if( response.isSuccess ){
                    // Login Success
                }
                else{
                    //Login Fail

                }
            },
            function(error){
                //Network related error
                $scope.HideSpinner();
            }
        );
```

Comment: the main problem is i need to put a progress bar before the data loads in the object in the html. so i think i need to get the html object to my controller which is i dont know if posible

Comment: You can call the ShowSpinner  method before loading the object and on finishing the object load you can call the HideSpinner method to hide it.

Comment: how do i call them without doing anything? i want to call them without clicking i just want them to show before the loading and automatically hide after

Comment: i want to give u some chart for this maybe its help



(file.pdf) --fetch--<controller>---(Progress Bar)--View(the html file)

Comment: I have added a small service call portion along with my code for showing and hiding spinner on a service call.

Answer (score 1):

Your English is really good and you need not worry about it at all. Coming back to your question, you are on the right path. You would need to use `ng-show` or `ng-hide`, whatever you choose. Let's say you choose `ng-show` In your controller, you would declare a variable,

```
$scope.isProgessBarVisible = true;
```

and then, within the controller itself, upon return from http call from the server, you would set it to false.

```
$http.get('someUrl')
 .then(function successCallback(response) {
 //load you pdf file content
 $scope.isProgessBarVisible = false;
}
```

And in the HTML

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-show="isProgessBarVisible" aria-valuenow="70"
   aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
   <object width="400" height="400" data="file.pdf"></object>
  </div>
```

With this in place, the progress bar will show up until the file is fetched from server and displayed.

Comment: the $scope.isProgressBarVisible set false already after the fetching of data thats why  the progressBar is not showing even the file is not yet fully loaded in the object. the main problem is i need to put a progress bar before the data loads in the object not on fetching hehe

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not just about showing/hiding the progress bar, perhaps it is about how to hide the progress bar **when the `<object>`'s content finish loading**.

Initially, I tried to use `ng-load` on the `<object>` but somehow it didn't work. So I tried to use `onload` which does work. But since the `onLoad()` handler function is outside angular environment, I had to get back the angular scope to be able to set the variable `$scope.showProgress` that will hide the progress bar.
See the plunkr yourself, and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

**Plunkr** https://plnkr.co/edit/wxgetLZdST0WcPEHyraZ

Note: I don't know whether it is possible to get the progress status number (% loaded), but at least we can show "Loading..." or a spinner icon while the `<object>` is loading.

Comment: the plnkr you should both show the loading and the image sir elfan

Comment: and yes your right. that's my problem the loading before the images is shown. i want to put progress bar between that

Comment: yes, the flow would be: (1) showing the "Loading..." and start load the `<object>`, (2) the `<object>` is loading, (3) when the `<object>` is loaded then hide the "Loading..."

Answer (score 0):

http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

```
angular.module('app', ['angular-loading-bar']);
```

angular-loading-bar is a good option for $http calls